# AngularJS V1.4.7 directive templateUrl dynamic path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having an issue with the `templateUrl:` portion of the angular directives.
I am trying to set a dynamic path however it does not seem to work and I can't figure it out. I checked the syntax and everything seems to checkout, it just does not pull the template from that URL.

Here is my directive code:

```js
var app = angular.module('docMan', ['ui.sortable']);

//global variable

app.run(['$rootScope','getResourceURL', function($rootScope, getResourceURL){

 getResourceURL('FOPS_Resource').then(function(result){$rootScope.FOPSbaseURL = result;
 },
      function(error){$scope.error = result;})

 
}]);

//Handle to grab SF info about the Static Resource base URL
app.factory('getResourceURL', ['$q','$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){

  return function (inputString) {

   var deferred = $q.defer();

   Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    'FO_Manager.GetResourceURL', 
    inputString,
    function(result, event){
     $rootScope.$apply(function(){
     if(event.status) {
      deferred.resolve(result);
     } else {
      deferred.reject(event);
     }
    })
   },
   {buffer: true, escape: true, timeout: 30000}
  );
  return deferred.promise;
 }
}]);

app.directive('sideNav', function($rootScope){

 return{

  restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
      info: '='
     },
     templateUrl: function($rootScope){ return $rootScope.FOPSbaseURL + '/js/custom/directives/sideNav.html';}

 };
});
```

Then when I put the tags `<sideNav info="SideNav"></sideNav>` where SideNav is in the scope of the controller surrounding it nothing happens the template does not get pulled.

Here is the template:`

```
                    <li class="mainCat">
                        <a href="#" id="CatHeader">
                            <i class="{{item.displayIcon}} left-bar"></i>
                            <span ng-bind-html="item.label | html"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="subCat"> 


                            <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.docTypes">
                                <a href="#" >
                                <i class="fi-folder"></i>
                                <span ng-bind-html="subItem.Name | html"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

`

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED:**

So the now thanks to the help below something did display but now the issues  is that `$rootScope.FopSbaseURL` doesn't populate properly in this `app.directive('foSidenav', function($rootScope){

```
return{

    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    templateUrl: function(){ 

        $rootScope.snipSideNav = $rootScope.FOPSbaseURL + '/js/custom/directives/sidenav.html';
        return $rootScope.snipSideNav;


    }
};
```

});
`
it is what I want in the rootScope but it doesn't pull in the templateURL

Comment: Do you see that at least app trying to hook your template with http request or your issue only missing $rootScope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AngularJS documentation:

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   `ngModel`). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. `ng-model`).

You should use this:

`<side-nav info="SideNav"></side-nav>`

More info in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: No problem :) I've realized that it is not only as tag names, it should be for any directive used in the view, I'm editing it now. I left `SideNav` as it was originally because I don't know if it's mean to trigger the directive or it is some other kind of reference he wants to use.

Comment: So the naming thing helped me resolve one issue, not it display something but now I am having another issue

Comment: Thanks that comment helped because now it displays something but I am having trouble accessing a variable in my rootscope

Comment: Any idea on how to get $rootScope.FOPSbaseURL to pass to templateURL

Comment: Hi, in order to debug that you will need to share your code in a JSFiddle so we can reproduce the problem and see if we can fix it, I am not familiar with `getResourceURL`, I don't know if it is even standard AngularJS, the documentation does not say anything about it.